# Ignore encoding in R

Tags: r, file-io, hex

Basically, the problem is simple. I want to manipulate a file which is in a strange encoding (settings file for a program I'm using). I can manipulate it by hand using Notepad++ such that what I want to happen happens. However, the file is full of NUL bytes, and R does not approve.

Using hexView I am able to read the file as hexadecimals, however, I am unable to export it or manipulate the file such that the necessary bytes/hexa's are changed. Are there any methods around this or am I destined to write my own package to do this?

Comment: How are you reading it now? And what do you want to do with it when you've read it in? You should be able to read the raw bytes with `scan(, what=raw)` or maybe `readBin` on a connection object.

Comment: I finally got it working using con <- file("", open="rb"); and then readBin(con, n=file.info()$size);. Going to try and writeBin(), hopefully I'll get it working.  Thanks for the reply MrFlick! I had already tried it, but forgot the n input.